# Is there a way to fix "Access violation - code c0000005 (!!! second chance !!!)" error

Tags: dll, kernel, windbg, drive

Some while ago when I open my computer and then WinDbg opens and gives me an error *Access violation - code c0000005 (!!! second chance !!!)*. I have no idea what this is and how to stop this popping up.

I tried to look at how to make this stop to pop up on every startup but haven't found anything.

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.10586.567 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

*** wait with pending attach

************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       symsrv*symsrv.dll*C:\Windows\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: symsrv*symsrv.dll*C:\Windows\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00007ff7`ebd50000 00007ff7`ebd68000   C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fe2a0000 00007ff9`fe481000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`ca070000 00007ff9`ca082000   C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\aswhook.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fb9a0000 00007ff9`fba52000   C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fa820000 00007ff9`faa93000   C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fb940000 00007ff9`fb99b000   C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fbee0000 00007ff9`fc004000   C:\Windows\System32\RPCRT4.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fb440000 00007ff9`fb538000   C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fc650000 00007ff9`fc972000   C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fa6f0000 00007ff9`fa76a000   C:\Windows\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fa620000 00007ff9`fa631000   C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fcb40000 00007ff9`fcbde000   C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fc4c0000 00007ff9`fc650000   C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fa6d0000 00007ff9`fa6f0000   C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fba60000 00007ff9`fba88000   C:\Windows\System32\GDI32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`faaa0000 00007ff9`fac32000   C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fb350000 00007ff9`fb3ef000   C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fb800000 00007ff9`fb82d000   C:\Windows\System32\IMM32.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f3a70000 00007ff9`f3a8d000   c:\windows\system32\wpnuserservice.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fa080000 00007ff9`fa098000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WLDP.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fb540000 00007ff9`fb722000   C:\Windows\System32\CRYPT32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fa5b0000 00007ff9`fa5c2000   C:\Windows\System32\MSASN1.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fa670000 00007ff9`fa6c7000   C:\Windows\System32\WINTRUST.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fcbe0000 00007ff9`fcc81000   C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`e8030000 00007ff9`e82d5000   c:\windows\system32\iertutil.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fe1c0000 00007ff9`fe269000   C:\Windows\System32\shcore.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fb8a0000 00007ff9`fb940000   C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`e66b0000 00007ff9`e6872000   C:\Windows\System32\wpncore.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fb730000 00007ff9`fb7f3000   C:\Windows\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fa5d0000 00007ff9`fa61c000   C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`e6410000 00007ff9`e64d1000   C:\Windows\System32\winsqlite3.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`e64e0000 00007ff9`e66a8000   C:\Windows\System32\urlmon.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fac40000 00007ff9`fb34d000   C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fc980000 00007ff9`fc9d1000   C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fa650000 00007ff9`fa66f000   C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fa640000 00007ff9`fa64a000   C:\Windows\System32\FLTLIB.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f2e60000 00007ff9`f2f3d000   C:\Windows\System32\WINHTTP.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f3030000 00007ff9`f317d000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wintypes.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`e8360000 00007ff9`e87e2000   C:\Windows\System32\cdp.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fe150000 00007ff9`fe1bc000   C:\Windows\System32\WS2_32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fb3f0000 00007ff9`fb439000   C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`edc60000 00007ff9`edc99000   C:\Windows\System32\XmlLite.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fa110000 00007ff9`fa135000   C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f9bb0000 00007ff9`f9be8000   C:\Windows\System32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fa4e0000 00007ff9`fa510000   C:\Windows\System32\SspiCli.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fa0e0000 00007ff9`fa106000   C:\Windows\System32\ncrypt.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f9fe0000 00007ff9`f9feb000   C:\Windows\System32\CRYPTBASE.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fa0a0000 00007ff9`fa0d6000   C:\Windows\System32\NTASN1.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`ef240000 00007ff9`ef36e000   C:\Windows\System32\NotificationController.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f3770000 00007ff9`f3785000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\usermgrcli.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f1b90000 00007ff9`f222b000   C:\Windows\System32\OneCoreUAPCommonProxyStub.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f96f0000 00007ff9`f9746000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\winsta.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f3180000 00007ff9`f31ff000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\policymanager.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f5080000 00007ff9`f5111000   C:\Windows\System32\msvcp110_win.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f1230000 00007ff9`f12bb000   C:\Windows\System32\QuietHours.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f5c00000 00007ff9`f5db8000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\twinapi.appcore.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f5ba0000 00007ff9`f5bc9000   C:\Windows\System32\RMCLIENT.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f5500000 00007ff9`f5513000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wtsapi32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`e5f50000 00007ff9`e5fa2000   C:\Windows\System32\execmodelclient.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f3b80000 00007ff9`f3d34000   C:\Windows\System32\PROPSYS.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f4fa0000 00007ff9`f507a000   C:\Windows\System32\CoreMessaging.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`e6b60000 00007ff9`e6b7a000   C:\Windows\system32\execmodelproxy.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f56e0000 00007ff9`f5778000   C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fc180000 00007ff9`fc2f3000   C:\Windows\System32\MSCTF.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`e9f80000 00007ff9`ea017000   C:\Windows\System32\TileDataRepository.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`ed480000 00007ff9`ed521000   C:\Windows\System32\StateRepository.Core.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`e34d0000 00007ff9`e3986000   C:\Windows\System32\Windows.StateRepository.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`e1590000 00007ff9`e163f000   C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Networking.Connectivity.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`ed000000 00007ff9`ed047000   C:\Windows\System32\usermgrproxy.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fb830000 00007ff9`fb838000   C:\Windows\System32\NSI.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`eb230000 00007ff9`eb298000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wlanapi.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f32a0000 00007ff9`f32b0000   C:\Windows\System32\dusmapi.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f2250000 00007ff9`f2275000   C:\Windows\System32\wcmapi.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`e1b80000 00007ff9`e1cb1000   C:\Windows\System32\Windows.StateRepositoryPS.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`eec40000 00007ff9`eec69000   C:\Windows\System32\Windows.StateRepositoryClient.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f9e30000 00007ff9`f9e96000   C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f3240000 00007ff9`f324b000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINNSI.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ff9`ec9a0000 00007ff9`ec9b6000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ff9`ec980000 00007ff9`ec99a000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ff9`d3f20000 00007ff9`d3fb4000   C:\Windows\System32\webio.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f9bf0000 00007ff9`f9cae000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`efa50000 00007ff9`efad8000   C:\Windows\System32\appresolver.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fc9e0000 00007ff9`fcb31000   C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`ea490000 00007ff9`ea4e0000   C:\Windows\System32\Bcp47Langs.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f9530000 00007ff9`f9557000   C:\Windows\System32\SLC.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fa4b0000 00007ff9`fa4d8000   C:\Windows\System32\USERENV.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f9500000 00007ff9`f9525000   C:\Windows\System32\sppc.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`e9870000 00007ff9`e987a000   C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f1ac0000 00007ff9`f1ad4000   C:\Windows\System32\threadpoolwinrt.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`e8fb0000 00007ff9`e9184000   C:\Windows\System32\Windows.CloudStore.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`e7760000 00007ff9`e788d000   C:\Windows\System32\wpnapps.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f9950000 00007ff9`f99c9000   C:\Windows\system32\schannel.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ff9`c3840000 00007ff9`c3854000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\mskeyprotect.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`c52b0000 00007ff9`c52d1000   C:\Windows\system32\ncryptsslp.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f9a50000 00007ff9`f9a5a000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DPAPI.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ff9`e9370000 00007ff9`e93c2000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\capauthz.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f9680000 00007ff9`f96b1000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`ee640000 00007ff9`ee64e000   C:\Windows\System32\TimeBrokerClient.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fa3f0000 00007ff9`fa408000   C:\Windows\System32\EventAggregation.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`dd760000 00007ff9`dd7ba000   C:\Windows\System32\wpnclient.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f0070000 00007ff9`f0209000   C:\Windows\System32\ContentDeliveryManager.Utilities.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`dafe0000 00007ff9`db466000   C:\Windows\System32\twinui.pcshell.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`fcd10000 00007ff9`fe150000   C:\Windows\System32\SHELL32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f5dc0000 00007ff9`f5de9000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`dfe80000 00007ff9`e019c000   C:\Windows\System32\DWrite.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f4ac0000 00007ff9`f4c5c000   C:\Windows\System32\dcomp.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f0730000 00007ff9`f079d000   C:\Windows\System32\wincorlib.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ff9`e7a60000 00007ff9`e7f1d000   C:\Windows\System32\WININET.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`f9350000 00007ff9`f940b000   C:\Windows\System32\dxgi.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`e09e0000 00007ff9`e0aff000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\mrmcorer.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`ea460000 00007ff9`ea489000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcp47mrm.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`e9920000 00007ff9`e9b7e000   C:\Windows\System32\msxml6.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`e6220000 00007ff9`e6293000   C:\Windows\System32\OneCoreCommonProxyStub.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`eb030000 00007ff9`eb03f000   C:\Windows\System32\npmproxy.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`ed560000 00007ff9`ed615000   C:\Windows\System32\AppXDeploymentClient.dll
(3114.1a88): Access violation - code c0000005 (!!! second chance !!!)
NotificationController!QuietHoursToastFilterSink::NotificationToastSlotNew+0x23d:
00007ff9`ef2ba24d 488b4050        mov     rax,qword ptr [rax+50h] ds:00007ff9`f3a61a88=????????????????
```

If I am correct is this some Windows process not working correctly on startup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault)

Comment: I would suggest the following:  Test 1 (quick). Rename "C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\aswhook.dll" to aswhook.dll.ren and reboot, does it still happen? Test 2, Download Procdump from Sysinternals, create C:\dumps\, save procdump in that location and then in an admin prompt run: `procdump -i -ma C:\dumps`. Next time it happens you should have a dump.  Maybe link that here.  Then run: `procdump -u`

Answer (score 3):

You seems to have set up WinDbg as the default post mortem debugger. In that case, it starts whenever a process dies from an exception.

To disable WinDbg as the post mortem debugger, go to Registry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug
```

or

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug
```

and rename the value `Debugger`.

If you want to find out which program dies due to the exception, type `|` to see the executable name. Save a crash dump using `.dump /ma accessviolation.dmp` so that you can do more analysis later (or give it to someone who can).

In your case, it seems to be `svchost.exe`, so a service dies.